Stable Baselines 3: The reason of fixing seed when load the model
I am studying Reinforcement Learning for prediction VWAP in intraday using PPO model(stable-baselines 3).
And the big problem was the model's reproducibility.
When I loaded and tested the trained model in my test environment, the model's results were different every time.
Even though my environment didn't have any randomness!
(When fix the seed of reset method, observation space, action space
I found two solutions that are consuming my time.
First, set the seed when load the model.
random_seed=42
# Set seed for reproducibility
torch.manual_seed(random_seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(random_seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(random_seed) # if use multi-GPU
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
np.random.seed(random_seed)
random.seed(random_seed)

Second, set the seed for every module at the beginning of my code.
# Load Model
model.load("./logs/ppo_vwap_predict_20240919_20240111.zip", env=env, seed=random_seed)

I can understand about second solution but cannot first.
Why random seed is needed when load the model?
I suspect that exploration and action selection (using np.choice) inside the PPO model is the cause.
I appreciate anyone who can give me ideas about my uncertain suspicion.
My Code is here (main.py)
import json
import datetime

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import SeedSequence, default_rng
import random

import gym
import talib as ta

import torch

from env.ExpectVolumeEnv import ExpectVolumeEnv
from env.ExpectVolumeEnvDiscrete import ExpectVolumeEnvDiscrete

from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3 import DQN
from stable_baselines3.common.callbacks import StopTrainingOnNoModelImprovement, StopTrainingOnRewardThreshold, EvalCallback
from stable_baselines3.common.monitor import Monitor
from stable_baselines3.common.callbacks import CheckpointCallback
from stable_baselines3 import HerReplayBuffer
from stable_baselines3.her.goal_selection_strategy import GoalSelectionStrategy

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


'''
reference
https://github.com/notadamking/Stock-Trading-Environment
'''

'''
Data
20XX-XX-XX KOSPI Intraday Data
'''

random_seed = 42

# # Set seed for reproducibility
# torch.manual_seed(random_seed)
# torch.cuda.manual_seed(random_seed)
# torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(random_seed) # if use multi-GPU
# torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
# torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
# np.random.seed(random_seed)
# random.seed(random_seed)

# Load data
df = pd.read_csv("data/raw/kospi_minutes/[지수KOSPI계열]일중 시세정보(1분)(주문번호-2499-1)_20240111.csv", encoding='cp949')

# DataFrame Preprocessing
df = df[df['지수명']=='코스피']
df = df[df['거래시각'] <= '1530']

data_date = str(df['거래일자'].iloc[0])

df = df[['거래시각', '시가', '고가', '저가', '종가', '거래량']]
df.columns = ['Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']

print(df)

df = df.astype(float)
df = df.reset_index(drop=False)


# # Create environment
env = ExpectVolumeEnv(df, seed=random_seed)
env.action_space.seed(random_seed)
env.observation_space.seed(random_seed)

# Create model (PPO)
model = PPO("MlpPolicy",
            env,
            learning_rate=0.00025,
            batch_size=128,
            verbose=1,
            )


# print(help(model.load))


# # Total timesteps / Number of steps per episode = Number of episodes
# model.learn(total_timesteps=len(df)*100)

# # # Save model
# model.save(f"./logs/ppo_vwap_predict_{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')}_{data_date}.zip")


# Load Model
model.load("./logs/ppo_vwap_predict_20240919_20240111.zip", env=env, seed=random_seed)

# observation, empty = env.reset(seed=random_seed)
observation, empty = env.reset()


print("mean: ", df['Close'].mean())
plt.plot(df['Volume'], label=f'{data_date} Market Volume')
plt.show()

plt.plot(df['Close'], label=f'{data_date} Market Close')
plt.show()

# Render each environment separately
for _ in range(len(df)-1):
    action, _states = model.predict(observation)
    observation, reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action)
    env.render()

market_vwap = env.render_plot(data_date=data_date)

volume_pattern = pd.read_csv('./data/volume.csv')
scaled_mean = volume_pattern['scaled_mean']

proportion = scaled_mean / np.sum(scaled_mean)

static_model_vwap = np.sum(df['Close'] * proportion)
print(f"Static Model VWAP: {static_model_vwap}")
print(f"Static Model VWAP Gap: {market_vwap - static_model_vwap}")


Please do not post code as images, see here for the reason.

You need to set model.predict(observation, deterministic = False).
